Styled components with react-native and typescript props
Hi I'm currently migrating a react-native project to use Typescript.
I have a lot of styled components which use props like this one :

    export interface LinkStyledProps {
      color: string;
      noUnderline: boolean;
    }



    export const S = {
      Wrapper: styled.TouchableOpacity<LinkStyledProps>`
        align-self: center;
        border-bottom-color: ${(props) => props.color};
        border-bottom-width: ${(props) =>
          props.noUnderline ? "0px" : "1px"};
      `,
    };


I passed as a generic the interface of my props and it should works but I still got the issue bind element have implicit type any.
Only workarround I found is to put again the type after props like that :

    border-bottom-color: ${(props: LinkStyledProps) => props.color};


But it sound like writing garbage extra code and anyway generic should work.
Maybe I'm missing some configuration somewhere, is anyone experiment same issue ?
Thanks for help
